# Laravel 8 application shows blank page on webserver

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess

So I am trying to run my Laravel 8 application on my server. I don't have root/SSH access, so I do everything with an FTP client. I uploaded all my content to my webserver and added my .htaccess file in order to run the application. It works fine in my local environment, but on my server it shows only a blank page. I put some debugging outputs in the public/index.php file and it can var_dump the $app variable.

```
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
var_dump($app); //Works
```

But it cannot var_dump $response.

```
$response = tap($kernel->handle(
    $request = Request::capture()
))->send();
var_dump($response); //Never reached statement
```

I guess it just aborts somewhere deep in the Laravel execution jungle and this would be hard to trace.

This is my project root .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

I cleared everythin in the storage folder but this doesnt make any impact. I also changed permissions of storage, vendor and bootstrap folder to 755 but it didn't change anything.

Locally it works both with php artisan serve or by placing everything in my htdocs folder of my XAMPP installation and browsing there.

What is the problem here?

Comment: Presumably there is another `.htaccess` file in the `public` subdirectory?

Comment: Personal recommendation, start using `Docker`, avoid `XAMPP` 100%. Also, avoid webservers that do not have `ssh` or does not allow you to have `apache/nginx` control... you must point your apache/nginx document root to `ROOT_PROJECT_FOLDER/public`. Also check `framework/logs` folder and see if you have any errors there.

Comment: @MrWhite yes, but even if I remove it, the error persists.

Comment: @matiaslauriti I have checked for the logs folder and the laravel.log is empty, it doesn't log any errors.

Comment: @frontend-newb My point is that if there isn't another `.htaccess` file in the `public` subdirectory (or it is incorrect) then your site is not going to work (except maybe the homepage). Certainly "removing it" is not going to help.

Comment: @MrWhite well, I used the pre-installed .htaccess file in the public dir. In the past I didn't have to modify it. I just had to put a .htaccess in the root directory and that was basically it.